# accepts_nested_attributes_for not creating attr writer method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

my guarantors model has_many addresses as :addressable and accepts nested attributes for addresses.  however, when whitelisting the address attributes, the params hash isn't recognizing addresses_attributes: [:street, :city, etc.]. I keep getting unpermitted parameters addresses.  anyone have trouble with this?

my models:

```
class UserApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :guarantors, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :guarantors
end

class Guarantor < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user_application, :foreign_key => :user_application_id
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

from the UserApplications Controller

```
    def user_application_params
  params.require(:user_application).permit(...,
                                           guarantors_attributes: [:id, :fname, :lname, :relationship, :phone, :email, :user_application_id, 
                                            addresses_attributes: [:id, :street, :street_2, :unit, :city, :state, :zip, :addressable_id, :addressable_type]]                                          
                                           )
end
```

the 'nested' part of the form:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :guarantors do |builder| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <h6>FIRST NAME</h6>
        <%= builder.text_field :fname, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h6>LAST NAME</h6>
        <%= builder.text_field :lname, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>      
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h6>RELATIONSHIP</h6>
        <%= builder.text_field :relationship, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>   
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h6>PHONE</h6>
        <%= builder.number_field :phone, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h6>EMAIL</h6>
        <%= builder.text_field :email, :class => "form-control" %>
      </div>     
    </div>
    <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |builder| %>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <h6>ADDRESS</h6>
          <%= builder.text_field :street, :class => "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <h6>ADDRESS 2</h6>
          <%= builder.text_field :street_2, :class => "form-control" %>
        </div>      
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <h6>CITY</h6>
          <%= builder.text_field :city, :class => "form-control" %>
        </div>   
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <h6>STATE</h6>
          <%= builder.text_field :state, :class => "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <h6>ZIP</h6>
          <%= builder.number_field :zip, :class => "form-control" %>
        </div>     
      </div> 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Finally, params:

```
"guarantors_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"fname"=>"blah", "lname"=>"", "relationship"=>"", "phone"=>"", "email"=>"", "id"=>"68"}, "1"=>{"fname"=>"", "lname"=>"", "relationship"=>"", "phone"=>"", "email"=>"", "id"=>"69"}}, "addresses"=>{"street"=>"", "street_2"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>"", "zip"=>""}, ...
```

I keep getting unpermitted parameters addresses and it's also not nested within guarantors_attributes.  Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you need `:address` to be plural in the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the Guarantor class? If that doesn't fix it, then it would be helpful to see the view with the form to make sure it's set up correctly to pass the hash under the key '*_attributes'

Comment: yes, editing question as you sent the message.  copy/paste error, it is actually :addresses in the model. will add form now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build your `fields_for :addresses`, I think you want that to be `builder.fields_for` since addresses are nested under guarantors.

```
f.fields_for :guarantors do |builder|
  # fields
  builder.fields_for :addresses do |builder|
    # fields
  end
end
```

#### code clarity

I would also make the block names more specific, since having 2 `builder` variables is confusing as to which scope you are in.

```
f.fields_for :guarantors do |guarantor_form|
  # fields
  guarantor_form.fields_for :addresses do |address_form|
    # fields
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you! builder.fields_for was the problem.  and thanks for the code clarity tip--still a newbie.